# Всплывающее окно только при первом посещении сайта (нужно сохранять куки)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, cookie

Есть сайт на **wordpress**. Подцепил всплывающее окно и теперь хочу его заставить появляться только раз для одного и того же пользователя. Для этого добавляю куки по этой [инструкции](http://dimox.name/popup-window-on-first-web-site-visit/comment-page-1). Саму библиотеку `cookie` подключил, пишу такой код при полной загрузке сайта

```
<script> $(window).load(function($){ 
$(function() {
  // Проверим, есть ли запись в куках о посещении посетителя
  // Если запись есть - ничего не делаем
  if (!$.cookie('was')) {

    // Покажем всплывающее окно
    $('#Modal').modal('show');

  }

  // Запомним в куках, что посетитель к нам уже заходил
  $.cookie('was', true, {
    expires: 365,
    path: '/'
  });
    });
}); </script>
```

Или такой

```
<script> jQuery(window).load(function(jQuery){ 
jQuery(function() {
  // Проверим, есть ли запись в куках о посещении посетителя
  // Если запись есть - ничего не делаем
  if (!jQuery.cookie('was')) {

    // Покажем всплывающее окно
    jQuery('#Modal').modal('show');

  }

  // Запомним в куках, что посетитель к нам уже заходил
  jQuery.cookie('was', true, {
    expires: 365,
    path: '/'
  });
    });
}); </script>
```

Получаю ошибку:

> Uncaught TypeError: jQuery is not a function

Что делаю не верно? Как поправить?

Comment: load(function($) не надо передавать алиас $. И далее оборачивать анонимкой то же нет нужды. Исправьте это, там видно будет

Comment: @Kirill Korushkin исправил, но пока ничего не видно, только ошибка сменилась с `jQuery` на `$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
(function($) {
  $(window).load(function() {
    // Проверим, есть ли запись в куках о посещении посетителя
    // Если запись есть - ничего не делаем
    if (!$.cookie('was')) {
      // Покажем всплывающее окно
      $('#Modal').modal('show');
    }
    // Запомним в куках, что посетитель к нам уже заходил
    $.cookie('was', true, {
      expires: 365,
      path: '/'
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
```

Данный пример выдаст Script error, однако это лишь по причине того, что исполняется в песочнице. Но **`Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function`** уже нет.

Comment: спасибо, а я как раз-таки и получаю ошибку 
`Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function` не помню, с чем это связано - возможно, с версией `jQuery` или не совместимостью, т.к. до подключения куки вот это работало хорошо
`<script> jQuery(window).load(function(){        
   jQuery('#Modal').modal('show');
    }); </script>`

Comment: Ну, это вордпресс и какие библиотеки подключены в вашем шаблоне и в каком порядке хз. Надо юзать noConflict как минимум. Сперва попробуйте обернуть анонимкой весь скрипт, я обновил в ответе.

Comment: о! вот это великолепно! Работает! Спасибо) в чем получается дело мне на будущее?

Comment: Скорее всего подключены разные js библиотеки в разном порядке. Когда оборачиваете анонимкой - указываете что внутри действует данный алиас ($) для данной библиотеки (jQuery). Почитайте про noConflict();

Comment: @KirillKorushkin WordPress всегда запускает jQuery в noConflict mode. Соответственно, все пользовательские скрипты должны оборачиваться примерно так, как вы указали в ответе. Я использую такую обертку jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {......});